# Show percentiles/tags on PDF export

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Very cool there's a PDF export in StackOverflow Careers now - copy/pasting into Word sucked. However, I noticed that the pecentiles/tags don't appear on it - they're one of the cool things about SO Careers! There should be an option to include them!